# Supporting MongoDB write when client is disconnected

Tags: mongodb, wifi, client-side, disconnect

I'd like to develop an app that uses MongoDB as the database, but which can cope with wifi dropout disconnects, so that the javascript client can cope with unreliable net connections, syncing when the connection is restored.

Does MongoDB support any kind of client-side API/data storage, and if not then what would be the best way to code the client so it can cope with wifi dropouts?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like every database: MongoDB does not support such a functionality. 
Use a message queue on the client side and feed your update requests as producer into the queue and add some consumer speaking to MongoDB fetching the data out of the queue.

Comment: and Andrei - Can I write to a client-side queue from a javascript/browser context? (apologies if my initial question didn't clarify that I'm browser-based here)

Comment: write *something* inside your web application for talking from browser to the queue

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need functionality like queue. So when client is disconnect your queue will be collect you actions, when connect is well you will send your actions from queue